# WinSCP - No supported authentications methods available - Unable to use key file... (SSH-1 Private Key)

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have an private key in SSH-1 format. When I associate it to my WinSCP site, I get the warning "Private key file... contains key in SSH-1 format. It does not follow your preferred SSH protocol version".

I ignore that and try to connect to an aws ec2 instance (I do not control) over sftp, I get:

No supported authentications methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) - Unable to use key file... (SSH-1 Private Key)

Do I need to convert my private key file? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

SSH-1 is obsolete for decades already. It's hardly ever used, maybe except for some legacy embedded devices. I'm quite sure that no AWS server supports that. And you cannot convert SSH-1 key to SSH-2. I cannot imagine, where you took the key from. In any case, you need to get a brand new key.